# Perl script not able to telnet to my switch

Tags: perl, switch-statement, telnet, cisco

I'm trying to write a perl code to telnet to a switch and then run a command. 
Here is the code

```
 my $device = "1.2.3.4";

 my $session = Net::Telnet->new(Host => "$device",
Input_log => "switchevi.log",
    );
$session->login('', 'intosh123');

# Execute a command
my @output = $session->cmd('show run');
print "@output\n";
$session->close;
```

The switch does not have a username. so as soon as you login , you get a password prompt.

When I execute this script, it gives me a error like

```
timed-out waiting for login prompt at switch.pl line 12
```

which is this line

```
$session->login('', 'intosh123');
```

please let me know what is going on.

Answer (score 0):

from cpan docs about login method:

> This method performs a standard login by waiting for a login prompt
>   and responding with $username, then waiting for the password prompt
>   and responding with $password, and then waiting for the command
>   interpreter prompt. If any of those prompts sent by the remote side
>   don't match what's expected, this method will time-out, unless timeout
>   is turned off.
>   
> ...
>   Consider using a combination of print() and waitfor() as an
>   alternative to this method when it doesn't do what you want, e.g. the
>   remote host doesn't prompt for a username.

so try something like this, insteed of `$session->login('', 'intosh123');`:

```
$t->waitfor('/password: ?$/i'); #here goes regex to match your password propmt
$t->print($passwd);
```

Also do not forget to set proper default prompt regex:

```
my $t = Net::Telnet->new(Timeout => 10,
                      Prompt => '/your regex goes here/');
```

And use debug option when something goes wrong